# UnicodeDecodeError django

Tags: python, django

I got this error when loaded localhost:8000 in django project, and it was the same case in every django project

```
'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 501470: invalid start byte
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8/barang/
Django Version:     1.8.4
Exception Type:     UnicodeDecodeError
Exception Value:    

Exception Location:     C:\Python27\lib\codecs.py in decode, line 296
Python Executable:  C:\Python27\python.exe
```

how can i resolve it?

Comment: Something somewhere is deciding that the incoming page is UTF-8 encoded, when it's really something else. Are you specifying that, or is it coming from somewhere else? Showing some code would be nice.

Comment: is it the problem?
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=mymodels.xls'
    wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
    ws = wb.add_sheet("DataPinjaman")

but in another project, i don't use this code

Comment: Go for Python 3. You'll never have this problem anymore. By the way, Django 2 will drop support for Python 2 and a lot of librairies have already been ported for Python 3.